# Advice on Python CSV formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a code to perform some simple csv formatting but I know it's not as good as it could be.

**Here's the input**

```
1,a
1,b
1,c
2,d
2,e
3,a
3,d
3,e
3,f
```

**Here's the output I want**

```
['1','a','b','c']
['2','d','e']
['3','a','d','e','f']
```

**This is the code I wrote**

```
import csv
input = csv.reader(open('book1.csv'))
output = open('output.csv', 'w')
job=[0,0]
for row in input:
    if row[0] == job[1]:
        job.append(row[1])
    else:
        print(job)
        #output.write(",".join(job))
        job[1] = row[0]
        job = [job[0], job[1]]
        job.append(row[1])
```

This is the output

```
[0,0]
[0, '1', 'a', 'b', 'c']
[0, '2', 'd', 'e']
```

**The questions I have are as follows**

How can I finish the else statement for the line? Also how can I get away with adding 0 as the zeroth element in the set. I also would like the code to output the last "job" set. Lastly does anyone have any suggestions for improving this code?

I ask because I would like to get much better at writing code, instead of just hacking it together. Any responses would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is group the second column by the first column. Python has a tool for that, [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
groups = itertools.groupby(input, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
```

is an iterator yielding `(key, group)` tuples, where the `key` is the first item in the rows, and each `group`is an iterator of lines in the group.

[`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)  does the same thing as the `[]` syntax -- gets the item specified. `operator.itemgetter(0)` is the same as:

```
def itemgetter_0(seq_or_mapping):
    return seq_or_mapping[0]
```

To extract the values and create lists, you can:

```
output = [[key] + map(operator.itemgetter(1), group) for key, group in groups]
```

which starts each list with the `key` and then extracts the second item from each line and adds them to the list.

For your example input, the output will be:

```
[['1', 'a', 'b', 'c'], ['2', 'd', 'e'], ['3', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'f']]
```

Answer (score 1):

To "get much better at writing code", you need to be able to write and understand nitty-gritty code, as well as knowing how to dial up an express delivery of `groupby` or whatever.

Attempting to answer the actual questions that you asked, here are the minimal changes needed to make your code work:

```
import csv
input = csv.reader(open('book1.csv'))
output = open('output.csv', 'w')
job = []
for row in input:
    if not job: # first row in input file
        job = row
    elif row[0] == job[0]:
        job.append(row[1])
    else:
        print(job)
        #output.write(",".join(job))
        job = row
if job: # emit the last job (if any)
    print(job)
```

Comment: I have a basic question on program flow. Regarding the last if statement "if job: print(job)" Why does it not print every job, only the last one? My assumption is that the code loops in the rows until it runs out, and then executes the last two lines but I would like to ask to double check.

Comment: @canyon289: the last `if` statement is indented to the same level as the `for` statement that precedes it, so it will be executed when the loop finishes. However, if it (and its accompanying `print()`) were indented 4 more spaces, then it would be executed for each input line -- not a good idea! Another way of looking at it: It's doing what you asked for (would like the code to output the last "job" set) ... try deleting those 2 lines and see what happens.